# Rotating symbols by Data Frame coordinate system in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, symbology, arcgis-pro, data-frame, rotate

Is it possible to ensure that symbols rotated by attribute (compass azimuth) retain their proper orientation when the Data Frame coordinate system changes?

Answers have been provided for this issue for ArcMap and for *labels* in ArcGIS Pro, but not for *symbols* in ArcGIS Pro.

As an example, I have a map with linear ESRI Cartography character symbols that are set to rotate in a "Geographic" rotation style so that the line points the compass direction specified by a field in the attribute table. This works completely fine in a geographic coordinate system where N is always up (WGS84). Unfortunately, when I change to a projected coordinate system (Lambert Conformal Conic North America), the lines no longer point in the correct compass directions on the map. For example, a line that should point N will point up on the screen even though in Alaska N is oriented to the top-right on the map in Lambert. In a projected coordinate system the symbols point the "wrong" way relative to all of the other features.

It is supposedly possible to correct this problem in ArcMap 10 (using the ArcMap Advanced Settings program) but I have not been able to do it in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Take a look at the [Calculate grid convergence angle tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-grid-convergence-angle.htm).

Comment: mkennedy, this is a clever workaround. Tentatively, the problem appears to be solved by using this tool to calculate the grid convergence angle in the desired coordinate system (Lambert), then adding that value to the "real" azimuth, and rotating by the result. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, whatever works. It's calculating the angle between "grid" (paper) north and geodetic north.